# Matrices en Python

Tags: python, matrices

tengo una duda con la creación de matrices en Python, específicamente con el siguiente código:

```
def inicializaMatriz(FILAS,COLUMNAS):
    matrizA = []
    for i in range(FILAS):
        a = [0]*COLUMNAS
        matrizA.append(a)
    return matrizA
```

Esta es una implementación que encontré, pero lo que no me queda muy claro es la línea:

```
a = [0]*COLUMNAS
```

Tengo una idea sobre lo que hace pero alguno sabe interpretar ésa línea?

Comment: ese codigo significa que a va a contener una lista del tipo [0] una COLUMNAS cantidad de veces, el operador * indica la cantidad de veces que se repetira [0] en la variable a, en este caso la cantiadad guardad en COLUMNAS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, el código en concreto que pides te crea una lista de ceros con la longitud de `COLUMNAS`.

Ahora una recomendación, si vas a trabajar con matrices/*arrays* en Python lo mejor es que utilices una librería especializada como `numpy`.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias por la ayuda y la recomendación.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [numpy.zeros](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html):

```
import numpy as np
rows    = 3
columns = 2
matrix =  np.zeros((rows,columns))
print matrix
[[ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Podemos crear matrices completa de ceros o con datos.

Primero importamos la librería `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

# creamos una matriz de 3*3 
matrizSoloCeros = np.zeros((3,3), int)

# creamos una matriz 4*4
matrizConNumeros = np.matrix([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])


print("matrizSoloCeros: \n", matrizSoloCeros)
print("matrizConNumeros: \n", matrizConNumeros)

matrizSoloCeros: 
 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

matrizConNumeros: 
 [[ 1  2  3  4]
  [ 5  6  7  8]
  [ 9 10 11 12]
  [13 14 15 16]]
```

`np.zeros((3,3), int)` creara una matriz de tipo int completa de ceros de 3 filas y 3 columnas.
`np.matrix([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])` creara una matriz de tipo int con los valores asignados en las listas.

##### Que hace el código provisto en la pregunta inicial?

Este código genera listas de listas según los valores de filas y columna ingresado por parámetros.

Si llamamos a la función `inicializaMatriz(FILAS,COLUMNAS)` de la pregunta inicial con los valores de filas y columnas obtendremos lo siguiente:

```
print("Lista de Listas:", inicializaMatriz(4,4))

Lista de Listas: [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

La variable `a` es una lista de ceros creada con el valor ingresado como parámetro para las columnas.

Para 4 columnas la variable `a` es agregada a las lista con la sublista.

```
a = [0]*COLUMNAS # El valor COLUMNAS es 4

# la variable es [0] multiplicado por cuatro
a = [0] + [0] + [0] + [0] Resultado: [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Espero que sea de utilidad.